# how to subset a data frame based on list of multiple match case in columns

Tags: r, data-cleaning

So I have a list that contains certain characters as shown below

```
list <- c("MY","GM+" ,"TY","RS","LG")
```

And I have a variable named "CODE" in the data frame as follows

```
code <- c("MY GM+","","LGTY", "RS","TY")
df <- data.frame(1:5,code)
df

  code
1 MY GM+
2 
3 LGTY
4 RS
5 TY
```

Now I want to create 5 new variables named "MY","GM+","TY","RS","LG"

Which takes binary value, 1 if there's a match case in the CODE variable

```
df 
   code    MY GM+ TY RS LG
1  MY GM+  1  1   0  0  0
2          0  0   0  0  0
3  LGTY    0  0   1  0  1
4  RS      0  0   0  1  0 
5  TY      0  0   1  0  0
```

Really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Since you know how many values will be returned (5), and what you want their types to be (integer), you could use `vapply()` with `grepl()`.  We can turn the resulting logical matrix into integer values by using `integer()` in `vapply()`'s `FUN.VALUE` argument.

```
cbind(df, vapply(List, grepl, integer(nrow(df)), df$code, fixed = TRUE))
#     code MY GM+ TY RS LG
# 1 MY GM+  1   1  0  0  0
# 2         0   0  0  0  0
# 3   LGTY  0   0  1  0  1
# 4     RS  0   0  0  1  0
# 5     TY  0   0  1  0  0
```

I think your original data has a couple of typos, so here's what I used:

```
List <- c("MY", "GM+" , "TY", "RS", "LG")
df <- data.frame(code = c("MY GM+", "", "LGTY", "RS", "TY"))
```

Comment: `library(SOfun); needleInHaystack(List, df$code)` :-) +1 -- very similar concept.